# Microsoft Word :How to start every section with different footer style?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2016, styles, footers, master

I am trying to start every section break with a centered page numbering style. I was able to have different sections linked together. However, I am supposed to have every section to have their own page number in the center.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the first page of each section to have centered page numbers in the footers and want the rest of the page numbers in the section to have page numbers elsewhere (or no page numbers at all) use the "Different First Page" setting in the header and footer controls.

This setting is by section, so each section needs to be set. When a new section is created, it will assume the setting already in place.

Answer (score -1):

You can find it in the [Zoom] option group and click [Multipage]

[image]

Comment: How does multipage allow to have different footer styles for every sections?